# How do I display different data in <router-outlet> if the user is logged in/out when using Angular?

Tags: angular, router

I am building a basic application that uses Session cookies to track if a user is logged in or not.

I want to display a "Sorry you can't see that" component in  if the user is logged out, and a "display the regular stuff" component if the user is logged in.  However, there is just the one  tag, and I can't figure out how to vary the component that goes there when the user is logged out.

Is there a way to do that, or am I way off-base?

Comment: you can write `authguard` and and an authorize component to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you only use one router and change where that router leads depending on the authentication of the user.

Have a look at the section of route guards in the angular documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

For example you can set up a route "admin" which is guarded and only show its children, if the user is authenticated.

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
          { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
          { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

---

Very important to note. The "real" authentication needs to happen on your backend.   Automatic rerouting in angular is helpful, but as the app runs on the client-side it could be changed to show whatever the server returns.